# Swift 5 Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, viewcontroller

This code is from my first view controller a.k.a the login page

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTxt: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: UITextField!

@IBAction func onLogInTapped(_ sender: Any) {



    guard let email = emailTxt.text,
    email != "",
    let password = passwordTxt.text,
    password != ""
        else {
            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Missing Info", message: "Please fill out all fields")
            return

    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let user = user else { return }
        print(user.user.email ?? "Missing Email")
        print(user.user.displayName ?? "Missing Display Name")
        print(user.user.uid)

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LogInPath", sender: nil)



    })

}
```

This code is from my sign up view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTxt: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: UITextField!

@IBAction func onCreateAccountTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let username = usernameTxt.text,
    username != "",
    let email = emailTxt.text,
    email != "",
    let password = passwordTxt.text,
    password != ""
        else {

            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Missing info", message: "Please fill out all fields")
            return

    }





    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in

        guard error == nil else{
            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let user = user else { return }
        print(user.user.email ?? "Missing Email")
        print(user.user.uid)





        let changeRequest = user.user.createProfileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest.displayName = username
        changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in

            guard error == nil else{

                AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUpPath", sender: nil)



        })


    })

}
```

This code is from my home view controller from which I should be displaying the user's name and also have the ability to log out.

```
@IBOutlet weak var welcome: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!


var databaseRef: DatabaseReference!






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    guard let username = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName else {return}



    welcome.text = "Hello \(username)"
    welcome.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen

    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
    layer.frame = view.frame
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    view.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)



}

@IBAction func onLogOutTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    do{
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LogOutPath", sender: nil)
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Finally, this code is from my alert controller which seems to not be working a function as when I put an invalid email and password it still performs the segue.

```
static func showAlert(_ inViewController: UIViewController, title: String, message: String){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    inViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Overall the issues are revolving around the window hierarchy thing and the alert controller not allowing invalid inputs.  I'm still new to Xcode and I don't know where the issue lies.

Comment: Welcome to SO. That's a lot of code for us to parse through and it would be helpful for you to do some troubleshooting before presenting a question. Add a breakpoint in your code and step through it line by line - examine the vars in the debugger until something doesn't look right - a nil var that's supposed to be populated, a typo etc. Also please ensure code is minimal - removing all of that dead while space (the returns between lines) can make it a lot shorter and easier to read. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, for clarity this function doesn't return a user `createUser( ...completion: {(user,`, it returns an AuthResult which may contain a user object. That part of the code works but the var names were confusing so wanted to mention that.